# Fetch first 5 and last 5 records through a single statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working on python sqlite3.

This statement gets records 5 - 14;

```
SELECT * FROM something LIMIT 5, 10;
```

But how do I get, lets say the first five and last five records through a single statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine output of two select statement like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM `something` order by some_column_name
limit 0,5)
union
(SELECT * FROM `something` order by some_column_name desc
limit 0,5
)
```

Specify some ordering of rows, so that it will select rows accordingly.

Comment: yes, its already same in example, `some_column_name`. Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the better way is using `rowid` in your `order by` clause to get the first and last rows based on inserting the rows:

```
select test from
(select test,rowid from table1 order by rowid asc limit 0,5)t1
union all
select test from
(select test,rowid from table1 order by rowid desc limit 0,5)t2;
```

Here is a sample in **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/272be/1)**